# Uninstall Aptana from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

Can someone please tell me how to uninstall Aptana from ubuntu 12.04 LTS? I followed [these instructions](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/), in summary:

1. Install the prerequisites with `apt-get install`.
2. Download Aptana Studio
3. Extract Aptana Studio

   ```
   sudo unzip [name of Aptana Studio ZIP file here].zip -d /opt
   ```
4. Add the menu shortcut

   ```
   wget http://www.samclarke.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/AptanaStudio3.desktop
   sudo mv AptanaStudio3.desktop /usr/share/applications/AptanaStudio3.desktop
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can probably figure out what directory the `zip` extraction created by using:

```
cd /opt
ls -lt | head
```

and remove the directory  (alternative is to use `unzip -l your_aptana.zip` to see what toplevel directories it contains.

Remove the menu item with:

```
rm /usr/share/applications/AptanaStudio3.desktop
```

The additional libraries can be uninstalled with

```
apt-get remove openjdk-7-jdk libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core
```

or, if you used OpenJDK:

```
apt-get remove libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core oracle-java7-installer
```

after which you should then also remove the extra file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Answer (score 2):

Replay the instructions backwards.

4. Remove the menu shortcut.

```
    sudo rm /usr/share/applications/AptanaStudio3.desktop
```

3. Remove the extracted files.

```
    sudo rm -r /opt/Aptana_Studio_3
```

2. Remove the downloaded zip file, if you wish.

1. Remove the dependencies, if you aren't using them for other things.

```
    sudo apt-get remove …
```